# how to log with chrome remote desktop into ubuntu

Tags: login, google-chrome, remote

my teenager daughter is pc addicted and i want to control her time and activities on using pc. I have installed Chrome Remote Desktop on Ubuntu 20.04 but got looped on login. Anyone can help?
Before i could use Chrome remote desktop to log her in the windows machine. can I do the same with Ubuntu?

Comment: This is a known issue. See if [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/9409642?hl=en&msgid=25469399) helps.

Answer (score 0):

`wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb && sudo apt install ./chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb`

then open installed Remote Chrome App, set the name and PIN.

Enjoy